# Elasticsearch Memory Issue - ES Process Consuming ALL RAM

Tags: memory, elasticsearch, ram

We are having an issue on our production Elasticsearch cluster where Elasticsearch seems to be consuming, over time, all of the RAM on each server. Each box has 128GB of RAM so we run two instances, 30GB is allocated to each for the JVM Heap. The remaing 68G is left for the OS and Lucene. We rebooted each of the servers last week and the RAM was started off just right using 24% of the RAM for each Elasticsearch process. It's now been almost a week and our memory consumption has gone up to around 40% per Elasticsearch instance. I have attached our config file in hopes that someone may be able to help figure out why Elasticsearch is growing out past the limit we have set for memory utilization.

Currently we are running ES 1.3.2 but will be upgrading to 1.4.2 next week with our next release.

Here is a view of top (extra fields removed for clarity) from right after the reboot:

> ```
>   PID USER       %MEM    TIME+  
>  2178 elastics   24.1   1:03.49 
>  2197 elastics   24.3   1:07.32
> ```

and one today:

> ```
>  PID USER       %MEM    TIME+  
> 2178 elastics   40.5   2927:50 
> 2197 elastics   40.1   3000:44
> ```

elasticserach-0.yml:

> ```
> cluster.name: PROD  
> node.name: "PROD6-0"  
> node.master: true  
> node.data: true 
> node.rack: PROD6
> cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.rack.values:
> PROD4,PROD5,PROD6,PROD7,PROD8,PROD9,PROD10,PROD11,PROD12
> cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: rack
> node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2  
> path.data: /es_data1  
> path.logs:/var/log/elasticsearch  
> bootstrap.mlockall: true  
> transport.tcp.port:9300  
> http.port: 9200  
> http.max_content_length: 400mb
> gateway.recover_after_nodes: 17  
> gateway.recover_after_time: 1m
> gateway.expected_nodes: 18
> cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries: 20
> indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec: 200mb
> discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 10  
> discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
> discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
> discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: XXX
> index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 10s
> index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 5s
> index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 2s
> index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn: 1s
> index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info: 800ms
> index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 500ms
> index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.warn: 10s
> index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.info: 5s
> index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug: 2s
> monitor.jvm.gc.young.warn: 1000ms  
> monitor.jvm.gc.young.info: 700ms
> monitor.jvm.gc.young.debug: 400ms  
> monitor.jvm.gc.old.warn: 10s
> monitor.jvm.gc.old.info: 5s  
> monitor.jvm.gc.old.debug: 2s
> action.auto_create_index: .marvel-*  
> action.disable_delete_all_indices: true  
> indices.cache.filter.size: 10%  
> index.refresh_interval: -1
> threadpool.search.type: fixed  
> threadpool.search.size: 48
> threadpool.search.queue_size: 10000000
> cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance: 6
> indices.store.throttle.type: none  
> index.reclaim_deletes_weight: 4.0
> index.merge.policy.max_merge_at_once: 5
> index.merge.policy.segments_per_tier: 5
> marvel.agent.exporter.es.hosts: ["1.1.1.1:9200","1.1.1.1:9200"]
> marvel.agent.enabled: true  
> marvel.agent.interval: 30s
> script.disable_dynamic: false
> ```

and here is /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch-0 :

> ```
> # Directory where the Elasticsearch binary distribution resides
> ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch
> # Heap Size (defaults to 256m min, 1g max)
> ES_HEAP_SIZE=30g
> # Heap new generation
> #ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE=
> # max direct memory
> #ES_DIRECT_SIZE=
> # Additional Java OPTS
> #ES_JAVA_OPTS=
> # Maximum number of open files
> MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
> # Maximum amount of locked memory
> MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
> # Maximum number of VMA (Virtual Memory Areas) a process can own
> MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144
> # Elasticsearch log directory
> LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch
> # Elasticsearch data directory
> DATA_DIR=/es_data1
> # Elasticsearch work directory
> WORK_DIR=/tmp/elasticsearch
> # Elasticsearch conf directory
> CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch
> # Elasticsearch configuration file (elasticsearch.yml)
> CONF_FILE=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.yml
> # User to run as, change this to a specific elasticsearch user if possible
> # Also make sure, this user can write into the log directories in case you change them
> # This setting only works for the init script, but has to be configured separately for systemd startup
> ES_USER=elasticsearch
> # Configure restart on package upgrade (true, every other setting will lead to not restarting)
> #RESTART_ON_UPGRADE=true
> ```

Please let me know if there is any other data I can provide. Thanks in advance for any help.

> ```
>             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
> Mem:        129022     119372       9650          0        219      46819
> -/+ buffers/cache:      72333      56689
> Swap:        28603          0      28603
> ```

Comment: It is not clear. Did you system actually ran out of memory?

Comment: It had, that's what prompted us to reboot the nodes in the cluster. We were dropping OOM error and Direct Memory errors all over the place... Now that they are at 80% we aren't getting errors yet, but I would like to find out how to prevent these two processes from consuming 100% of the RAM.

Comment: can you run free -m and add the results to your question? And do you mean a JVM OOM exception or an invocation of the Linux OOM killer?

Comment: Output added to original message. Although I did a rolling restart on each node to avoid any surprises over the weekend.

Comment: Facing same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing isn't heap blow out, heap will always be restricted by what you set in the config. free -m and top report on OS related use, so the use there would most likely be the OS caching FS calls.

This will not cause a java OOM.

If you are experiencing java OOM, which is directly related to the java heap running out of space, then there is something else at play. Your logs may provide some info around that.

Comment: I completely agree with your statement, the heap should stay within the limits of what I set. The question is how do I keep the OS from caching so many FS calls. Is there any way to bind this so it flushes and doesn't start killing my cluster? The thing that is confusing is that according to TOP this memory is being consumed by the elasticsearch process... is there way to tell the ENTIRE ES process to stop consuming at a certain point rather than just the heap?